# how to detect new line in this type of string

Tags: java, android

```
String quote = "Now is the time for all good "+
               "men to come to the aid of their country.";
```

I want to detect break line in run time when I click on button I want to know new line comes..
because in TEXTVIEW i want output same as like this String nothing change.. so tell me some idea or logic or source code of this....

Comment: Can you seperate each section with a non-visible character like a "\n"

Comment: @user642 like @aioobe in his answer says, there is no newline in the string in your question. Is this a typo? Is there a `\n` anywhere in your string?

Comment: ya i want to sperate some words by invisble "\n"

Comment: If you want to continue receiving great answers like the ones below, you need to accept answers that help you. Click on the check mark to the left of the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The '\n' character specifies a line break.

```
"Now is the time for all good\nmen to come to the aid of their country."
```

If your GUI is breaking the line before this point you need to disable word wrapping somehow.

Answer (score 9):

There are no new-lines or special "break-line" characters in

```
String quote = "Now is the time for all good "+
               "men to come to the aid of their country.";
```

The statement is entirely equivalent to

```
String quote = "Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country.";
```

> **When I click on button I want to know new line comes..**

You can find out where each new-line is by doing `yourText.indexOf("\n")`. The snippet below for instance, prints 29.

```
String quote = "Now is the time for all good \n" +
               "men to come to the aid of their country.";

System.out.println(quote.indexOf('\n'));
```

> **ya i want to sperate some words by invisble "\n"**

There are no "invisible `\n`". In source code, you have to use `\n` or something equivalent. Java does not support [heredoc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document) or anything equivalent to that.

To break up a string into multiple lines, you could do something like:

```
String quote = "Now is the time for all good " +
               "men to come to the aid of their country.";

quote = quote.substring(0, 29) + "\n" + quote.substring(29);

System.out.println(quote);
```

which prints:

```
Now is the time for all good 
men to come to the aid of their country.
```