# Formatting java code using Java

Tags: java, formatting, format

I wanted to format Java code so that i can extract conditions associated with if and while.

Conditions like:

```
if (condition1 && condition2) { /* Statements; */ }
```

should be like:

```
if (condition1 && condition2)
{
//Statements;
}
```

This way conditions associated with if can be fetched.

I wanted to do this using Java so i am not using any parsing tools.
I also do not want to format code using eclipse.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't want to use any parsing tools, but you **are** writing one, therefore your question doesn't make any sense. If you could work out how to reformat the code, you could parse the code in the first place and negate the need for reformatting.

Comment: *I wanted to do this using java so i am not using any parsing tools.*, that statement make little sense to me. Why can't you use a Java parser like [javaparser](http://code.google.com/p/javaparser/) (to name just one parser) that you can call from your own Java code?

Comment: And why don't you want to use Eclipse's (or any other IDE's) code formatter for this?

Answer (score 0):

Statements like `if` etc. always follows a defined syntax so you shouldn't need to reformat your code to parse them. Maybe simple regexes can do that for you. You should think about that point instead of writing a code formatter. The java compiler can parse code independent from its layout.

Answer (score 0):

Without getting into why would you like to do what you want to do, and considering that fact you didnt show any code, ill provide you some links which may give you some ideas.

You will need to [parse your code](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~hasti/cs302/examples/Parsing/parseString.html) so you can detect and replace [new lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5090494/how-to-detect-new-line-in-this-type-of-string), using [regular expressions](http://www.vogella.de/articles/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html) can help you a lot.

Comment: But you can split each line according to the Semicolon (;) would'nt be easier to work with line separated codelines?